# bootstrap Select options scroll not appear

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I built a form for products with bootstrap v4. In the select category section when i click to select the options instead of dropdown it will show dropup and scroll will appear. I also try in css using .over class for appearing scroll for dropdown but nothing happens it still show dropup. What i want is when user click to select the category it will shown dropdown in a descent manner. Any idea how to do this .?

```
<select name = "category" id="category" class="form-control over">
                           <?php
                         foreach ($catlist as $category)
                         {
                         if (isset($_POST["category"]) && $_POST["category"] == $category)
                         echo "<option selected='selected' value='$category'>$category</option>";
                         else
                         echo "<option value='$category'>$category</option>";
                         }
                         ?>


                    </select>
```

My css code i tried is

```
.over{ overflow: scroll;}
```

or

```
.over{overflow: visible;}
```

In php category list would be like this

```
$catlist = array ("1", "2", "3" .... "26")
```

EDIT: Dropdown works untill 14 options but when i tried 15, it will show like dropup. There are more then 26 categories now.

Comment: I did not understand very well what you want to do but I think you want to show in the SELECT the options descending, that is, 26,25,24 ... 3 ... 2 ... 1?

Comment: I want to show the options in a drop down manner and if limit excced then scroll will appear.